# commandButton double action : save and redirect to other page

Tags: javascript, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf, jspx

I would like after click on save button, data should be saved and user redirected to corbeille page. This is my current implementation :

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="boutonAction buttonSaveDossierAppel"
value="#{messages['save.btn.save.label']}"
update="editForm"
action="#{consultDossier.save()}"                               
disabled="#{editDossier.isEditAccess() == 'false'}"
ajaxSingle="false" immediate="false" limitToList="true"                                                         
reRender="msg" />
```

I tried with this :

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="boutonAction buttonSaveDossierAppel"
value="#{messages['save.btn.save.label']}"
update="editForm"
action="#{consultDossier.save()}"
action="#{commonNavigationAction.manageAccessibility('E53CORBEILLE')}"                          
disabled="#{editDossier.isEditAccess() == 'false'}"
ajaxSingle="false" immediate="false" limitToList="true"                                                         
reRender="msg" />
```

it is not working !

How can I do this ?

Comment: Have only one action. Have the save method return type as String. After you save the values, return the path to your welcome page or the navigation case to your welcome page. E.g return "welcome.xhtml?redirect-faces=true"

Comment: Or you can do save () in actionListener and have action="welcome.xhtml?redirect-faces=true"

Comment: @Mahendran: nothing in the question implies that OP is using JSF 2.x. Moreover, `reRender` attribute implies RichFaces 3.x which strongly suggests JSF 1.x. The [jspx] tag on question only confirms JSF 1.x more as JSP is deprecated in JSF 2.x and no one sane developer would use it in JSF 2.x. Better ask OP which JSF version exactly he is using before suggesting JSF 2.x specific solutions.

Comment: @BalusC oh thanks. My inexperience in richfaces is showing. So I am thinking aloud here. So h:outputLink or navigation case?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way: Just return your welcome page full path on your consultDossier.save() method.

```java
public String save(){
  //Save....//
  return "welcomepage.xhtml"
}
```

Comment: OP asked to perform a redirect, not a forward.

Comment: I do Agree with BalusC and I would like to manage this through my jspx

Answer (score 0):

To enable page redirection just add "?faces-redirect=true" in the end of the string return on the bean.

```
public String save(){
  //Save....//
  return "welcomepage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
}
```

As pointed by BallusC, this answer works in JSF 2.x only, sorry.
You could use the onComplete attribute of the a4j button to execute the redirect, which version of JSF are you using?

[tag documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html)

Comment: This answer works in JSF 2.x only. OP did nowhere imply/confirm that he is using JSF 2.x.

Comment: Since i'm new to JSF, i have not worked with versions before 2.0 and cant do much to help you.
About the a4j button, as told above 2 actions will not work, you can try to change the second one to the onComplete attribute, it will execute its method after the request has been completed. 
Good Luck and hope your problem will be solved soon